# How to connect Uart to serial data output?

Tags: uart

[image]

A small DAQ converts some sensor value to digital outputs.
Since we need analog output, it has an analog converter. DAQ serial output
will go the analog converter. But Im confused with wirig DAQ and the analog converter.
The thing is Im kind of confused with the terminology of serial
connections.

In my diagram which pin will wired to where?

Comment: can you post the link of both the datasheets.

Comment: its DAQ (data acqusiton) not DAC

Comment: They must have some information on the electrical aspects of the interface and the protocols used otherwise you waste too much time having to hack the product. If the information is not available find a different product. My boss would not want me wasting time reverse engineering anything when for a little more money all the information is supplied.

Comment: Do not overlook the communications protocols. If the interpretation of the data-stream is not compatible, you will need something more than just a hardware interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither CAN nor SPI are UART data. By elimination, Data-out nets with UART-RX and Data-In to UART-TX.

Comment: thanks how about Ground to Ground? Or power to power as well connected?

Comment: Yep, ground-ground, power-power

Answer (score 0):

You have a CAN and SPI data, CAN: CAN-HI, CAN-LO, GND. SPI: MISO (Data-in), MOSI)data-out), CLK, CS, GND.
No UART data.

Comment: I have to connect to UART. Do u mean what u write is alternativd to the commentator above??

Comment: You have to connect only specific supported hardware on your DAQ board, that probably goes to SPI port. Your DAQ has to have a device driver that reads/writes to the analog output (if such possibility exists), you can't hook up an analog converter of your choice, it makes sense, since SPI is much faster than UART.

Comment: The same company sent both daq and anal converter

Comment: Then ask them to send you a manual, since they have sold you the equipment.

Comment: If I followed above users suggestion it works. So Data-in to Uart-Tx ect. It means There is UART since it works. Why did you think theres no Uart?

Answer (score 0):

DAQ has a SPI interface, so SPI-to-UART Bridge can be used in-between to interface DAQ and Analog converter. As an example HT45B0F full fills this requirement. Datasheet can be found [here](http://www.holtek.com/pdf/computer/ht45b0fv110.pdf)

Block diagaram is as below

[image]

Its a microcontroller peripheral device to implement SPI-to-UART data conversions. The UART module can operate in full-duplex mode with an interrupt output capability to the host microcontroller.